# Launching Google Maps with "My Location" as the starting point label

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

i use the following code to launch `Google Maps` to show step by step navigation from my current location to a specific location:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f",destLocation.coordinate.latitude, destLocation.coordinate.longitude,_currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,_currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]];
```

however, when `Google Maps` app opens, it displays for example "Howard Street" as the starting point label, which is correct, but how can I let `Google Maps` app displays "My Location" label instead of the street name label as the starting point ?

p.s. the user can display "My Location" label if he/she taps on the coordinates, then choose "My Location" as the starting point from inside `Google Maps`, but I want this behavior to be done on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 0):

from [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme), if I didn't provide the source coordinates, Google Maps will automatically display "My Location" as the starting point label.